# How to add an image onto an object

Tags: rendering, image

I want to put a 2D image onto a 3D object. I have downloaded the image, and just can't find out how to add it onto the object. Thanks! (v2.80.75)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: For basic questions you can use the search box at the top. There is a lot of information on this site. Feel free to go get it.

Comment: You should read this guide. It is thorough (read: long), but important. You only need to know the sections about Image textures and UV mapping for now, but I would recommend reading the whole thing anyway to get a good understanding of how textures work in blender (and other 3D software for that matter). - https://artisticrender.com/how-to-add-a-texture-to-an-object-in-blender/

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, you want to add an image to Cube. Select **Texture Tab** -> Base Color -> Image Texture

[image: Select Image Texture]

Now select Open an Image required. Image will apply to Object.

[image]